# System.Security.Cryptography.RSA missing from mscorlib 5.0.5.0

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-5.0, mscorlib, .net-4.5.2

I have a project that is throwing an error on the following line:

```
var rsaCrypto = new RSACrypto(1024);
```

`RSACrypto` was located in `System.Security.Cryptography.RSA` of **mscorlib 4.0.0.0**.

However, that is not so with **mscorlib 5.0.5.0** (confirmed via Object Browser):

[image]

What gives? How do I get RSA back so I can compile?

Comment: Afaik mscorlib 5.0.5.0 is for Silverlight 5... Are you creating a Silverlight app?

Comment: Are you sure? MSDN says [RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.RSA(v=vs.110).aspx) is a class, without any sub classes. Can you link the MSDN documentation article?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: http://http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.  However, it is not available in Silverlight.

Comment: @SLaks: that is another class then in the code from OP. Also the namespace is different.

Comment: @DaveZych - Yes it is Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question comments, **@DaveZych** mentioned that **mscorlib [5.0.5.0]** is Silverlight 5 and both **@PatrickHofman** and **@SLaks** mentioned that [`RSA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa) is *not* available in Silverlight.

They are all correct, and as it turns out, it wasn't the `mscorlib` assembly reference at all.

It was missing [DH.Scrypt.dll](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/DH.Scrypt.dll) which is an assembly that [Dustin Horne](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/DustinHorne) wrote and published to http://scrypt.codeplex.com/ so that RSA Cryptography can be used in Silverlight 3, 4, and 5.